# Refresh a WPF Page

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an application that I have written to view logs from custom applications that have been written for this company.  I have it set up using an Entity Model and would like to dynamically change which database I am hitting (test database or production database) based on a menu selection.  I have tried using an EntityConnectionStringBuilder and it appears to work with no errors, however I can not get the grid that displays the list of applications to update after changing the data connection string. (the connection strings for test and production servers are stored in the properties.settings)  Here is what I have for switching to the test server

```
try
{
  XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
  var query1 = from p in doc.Descendants("connectionStrings").Descendants()
             select p;
  foreach (var child in query1)
  {
    foreach (var atr in child.Attributes())
    {
        if (atr.Name.LocalName == "name" && atr.Value == "AppsEntities")
        if (atr.NextAttribute != null && atr.NextAttribute.Name == "connectionString")
        {
            EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(atr.NextAttribute.Value);
            entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default["TestServer"].ToString();
            atr.NextAttribute.Value = entityBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
  }
  doc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
  lblDatabase.Content = "Connected to the Test Server";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show("changing connection string to Test - blew up!" + ex.Message, "massive error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated I am new to C# and WPF's so I may not be going about this the correct way.

```
 <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="LogApplicationGrid"
                         Width="900"
                         Height="Auto"
                         Margin="2,53,0,0"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                         GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal"
                         IsReadOnly="true"
                         MouseDoubleClick="LogApplicationGrid_MouseDoubleClick"
                         ShowGroupPanel="False">
        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn MaxWidth="50"
                                        DataMemberBinding="{Binding AppID}"
                                        Header="AppID"
                                        IsFilterable="False"
                                        UniqueName="appNumber" />
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn MaxWidth="300"
                                        DataMemberBinding="{Binding AppName}"
                                        Header="Application Name" />
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn MaxWidth="350"
                                        DataMemberBinding="{Binding AppDesc}"
                                        Header="Application Description" />
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn MaxWidth="150"
                                        DataMemberBinding="{Binding DateCreated}"
                                        Header="Date Created"
                                        IsFilterable="False" />
            <telerik:GridViewCheckBoxColumn MaxWidth="100"
                                            DataMemberBinding="{Binding ShowInSharePoint}"
                                            Header="SharePoint"
                                            IsFilterable="False" />
        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    </telerik:RadGridView>
```

Comment: If you have verified that the connection does indeed switch, then this sounds more like a data binding issue and you should post the relevant XAML and the `DataContext` for the XAML.

Comment: When I say it appears to work - Visual Studio in debog mode does not catch any errors, however I am in unfamiliar territory with this - the App.config file never seems to change if that helps.  I have run the application with each connection string seperately and they each work so I agree in that it is either the code posted above or the Bindings.

Comment: Where is your GridView getting it's data from? Ideally its `ItemsSource` should be bound to a collection in the `DataContext`, and to update the grid you just update the collection.

Comment: I am pulling the data into a list<> and attaching that to the ItemsSource right after the InitializeComponents()

Comment: Ok after more debuging I have determined that the connectString is not getting updated - does anyone know if you have 2 identical databases - can you use the same Entity Model and just change the connection strings back and forth?  I am beginning to think this is not a good idea.

Comment: @BradG Yes, that is possible. Just google `entity framework multiple databases` and it should be one of the top links

Comment: @Rachel Thanks I found a solution that works - I added a second connection string and switch between them as needed - works great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind your GridView to an `ObservableCollection<T>`, then to update your Grid's data, simply update the collection.

Use an `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of a `List<T>` because it will automatically alert the UI that it needs to be updated when the collection changes.

Also, be sure you're binding the value instead of setting it. Setting the value will set the value to an instance of the data, not the actual data itself, so it won't respond to changes.

For example, this will not update the UI

```
LogApplicationGrid = SomeCollection;
SomeCollection = GetObservableCollection();
```

But this will

```
var b = new Binding();
b.Source = SomeCollection;
LogApplicationGrid.SetBinding(RadGridView.ItemsSourceProperty, b);

SomeCollection = GetObservableCollection();
```

and this also will

```
<telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}" ... />
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.  I have things changed over to the _ObservableCollection<T>_ And in through stepping back through the code line by line I have discovered that the ConnectionString is not getting updated like it should...